# Why is my else statement leaving an error?

Tags: java

Hi I'm a beginner in java I would just like to know why I'm getting an error message for else ('else without 'if').

```
public class Exercise6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String user = Input.askString("Username:");
    String pass = Input.askString("Password:");
    if (user.equals("joe") || pass.equals("guess"));
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome, joe!");
        } 
            else
        {
            System.out.println("Incorrect username or password.");    


    }
}
}
```

Comment: You have a semicolon at the end of your `if` statement.

Comment: I belief , you are using an IDE and this seems to be a compilation error which could have been caught in IDE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking your code problem is or semicolon(;) after If statement. in that what, if statement will be end there so else will left out alone. so corrrect one is here:

```
public class Exercise6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String user = Input.askString("Username:");
    String pass = Input.askString("Password:");
    if (user.equals("joe") || pass.equals("guess"))
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome, joe!");
        } 
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Incorrect username or password.");    
        }
    }
}
```

Also you can do it like;

```
public class Exercise6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String user = Input.askString("Username:");
    String pass = Input.askString("Password:");
    if (user.equals("joe") || pass.equals("guess"))
        System.out.println("Welcome, joe!");
     else
        System.out.println("Incorrect username or password.");    
    }
}
```

This is because if there is single statement in if or else part then there is no need of braces.. i hope you have got idea.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like **your trying to check username and password** . Your OR condition also wrong .See the change in my code.   **Needs to replace || to &&**

And **remove the semicolon** from if condition

```
 public class Exercise6 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        String user = Input.askString("Username:");
        String pass = Input.askString("Password:");
        if (user.equals("joe") && pass.equals("guess"))
        {
            System.out.println("Welcome, joe!");
            } 
                else
            {
                System.out.println("Incorrect username or password.");    
        }
    }
    }
```